# Determining the dimension of V: is this correct?

Tags: self-learning, matrices

For clearance: am I doing it right?

[image]

So, I have the vector in *`REF`*, which gives me:

```
1 1 -1 2
0 1 -3 1
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

So, we have a rank of 2, hence: we have two pivot columns. We have a nullity of two, because we have two columns without a pivot *(= free variables = nullity)*, so the dimension should be:

```
Dimension = Rank (2) + nullity (2) = 4
```

Am I correct or not?

Comment: The dimension of a subspace $V$ is the number of linearly independent vectors that span $V$.

Comment: @WaveX No, he is correct because he found out that only two ouf of its four vectors are linearly independent and thus $\;\dim V=2\;$ , not four.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah I just checked to see if the vectors were linearly independent or not. I went under the assumption that they were, but turns out they aren't

Comment: The dimension of a subspace V is the number of linearly independent vectors that span V? Can someone explain to me what exactly this is when I'd check my REF matrix? I still don't get it. Why is 4 wrong? Isn't the formula I am using the formula I need to use?

Comment: I don't know what a REF matrix is, but the two lines of zeros at the bottom seem to indicate a two dimensional nullspace.

Comment: Please don’t include important parts of your question as images. They’re not searchable and are inaccessible to people using screen readers.

Comment: You appear to be confusing the dimension of the overall space $\mathbb R^4$ with the dimension of the subspace $V$.

Comment: @amd: what's the difference?

Comment: A line is one-dimensional no matter how many slots there are in the tuples that describe the points on it. It doesn’t matter whether we’re talking about a line in $\mathbb R^2$, $\mathbb R^3$, &c. A line is one-dimensional in all of those spaces. For an extreme example of this, consider the vector space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Its dimension isn’t even countable, but the subspace of constant functions within this space is one-dimensional.

Comment: @Siyah i would suggest you to read up any linear algebra text of your choice on the topic of vector space, linear (in)dependence, basis. Implementing the dimension theorem here seems redundant when all you have to do is to check for linear (in)dependence of the 4 vectors.

Comment: Little Rookie... because we have a rank of two, it means we have two linear independent vectors, thus dimension should be two.. is this correct?